Media Recorder Audio JS not work browser mobile
I'm building a web-app that will be used by tablets and I'm hoping someone can help me solve the puzzle that's been plaguing me for 2 days.
I am developing the function in Javascript that allows me to record multiple audio files and preview them in a gallery in the browser and then send them back. Everything works correctly in Firefox browser (PC) but from PC Chrome and Android Chrome the microphone is not activated for registration. The registration does not work on the tablet for different browsers. Below I inserted the JS and HTML code.
I really hope someone can tell me why it works on PC but not on tablet. The microphone permissions are all there.
The problem: this code only works on mozilla firefox (PC) the error on all other mobile browsers and permission is not denied to the microphone despite the permissions being allowed
let mediaRecorder;
let audioChunks = [];

const recordButton = document.getElementById('recordButton');
const audioGallery = document.getElementById('audioGallery');

recordButton.addEventListener('click', async() => {
  if (!mediaRecorder) {
    try {
      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: true
      });
      mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
      mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = event => {
        audioChunks.push(event.data);
      };
      mediaRecorder.onstop = () => {
        const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks, {
          type: 'audio/webm'
        });
        const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);
        audioChunks = [];
        addAudioToGallery(audioUrl);
      };
      mediaRecorder.start();
      recordButton.classList.add('recording');
      recordButton.textContent = 'Ferma Registrazione';
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Errore durante la registrazione:', error);
      alert('Impossibile accedere al microfono. Assicurati di aver concesso i permessi. Errore: ' + error.message);
    }
  } else {
    mediaRecorder.stop();
    recordButton.classList.remove('recording');
    recordButton.textContent = 'Avvia Registrazione';
    mediaRecorder = null;
  }
});

// Funzione per aggiungere l'audio alla galleria
function addAudioToGallery(audioUrl) {
  const audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
  audioElement.controls = true;
  audioElement.src = audioUrl;
  audioGallery.appendChild(audioElement);
}

function addAudioToGallery(audioUrl) {
  const audioItem = document.createElement('div');
  audioItem.classList.add('audio-item');
  const audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
  audioElement.controls = true;
  audioElement.src = audioUrl;
  audioElement.name = "audios[]";
  const removeBtn = document.createElement('button');
  removeBtn.classList.add('remove-btn-record');
  const imgDelete = document.createElement('img');
  imgDelete.src = "/css/external/Icone/Delete.svg";
  imgDelete.id = "delete";
  imgDelete.alt = "Rimuovi";
  removeBtn.appendChild(imgDelete);
  removeBtn.onclick = () => {
    audioGallery.removeChild(audioItem);
    removeAudioFromInput(audioUrl);
  };
  audioItem.appendChild(audioElement);
  audioItem.appendChild(removeBtn);
  audioGallery.appendChild(audioItem);
  addAudioToInput(audioUrl);
}

function addAudioToInput(audioUrl) {
  const hiddenInput = document.getElementById('hiddenAudioInput');
  fetch(audioUrl)
    .then(response => response.blob())
    .then(blob => {
      const file = new File([blob], 'audio_' + Date.now() + '.wav', {
        type: 'audio/wav'
      });
      const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();
      for (const file of hiddenInput.files) {
        dataTransfer.items.add(file);
      }
      dataTransfer.items.add(file);
      hiddenInput.files = dataTransfer.files;
    });
}

function removeAudioFromInput(audioUrl) {
  const hiddenInput = document.getElementById('hiddenAudioInput');
  const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();
  for (const file of hiddenInput.files) {
    if (!file.name.includes(audioUrl)) {
      dataTransfer.items.add(file);
    }
  }
  hiddenInput.files = dataTransfer.files;
}

<label for="recordButton">
  <img src="{{ asset('/css/external/Icone/iconemicvideo/Voice 2.png') }}" class="crea1-paperclip-1" alt="Allega" style="top: 29px; left: 186px; z-index:1;" />
</label>
<input type="button" id="recordButton" />
<input type="file" id="hiddenAudioInput" name="audios[]" multiple hidden />
<div id="audioGallery" class="gallery">
  {{-- Posizionamento media --}}
</div>

Is this a compatibility problem?

If you have tested on multiple devices and multiple browsers, it might be compatibility problem. You can useRecordRTC [RecordRTC][1]. or go to their live demo and test if it works: [Live Demo of Record RTC][2].
[1]: https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC?tab=readme-ov-file
[2]: https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/

If you have tested on multiple devices and multiple browsers, it might be compatibility issue. You can useRecordRTC RecordRTC. or go to their live demo and test if it works: Live Demo of Record RTC. It supports following browsers:

